# Goroutine storage channel value has no deadlock

Tags: go

This code runs and ends with no deadlock error.  Why?

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        ch<-1
        ch<-2
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Comment: The gorountne is blocked forever, but the application exits when main returns.

Comment: What is a "Goroutine storage channel"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unbuffered channel needs two end points to work, so let's start with correct example:

```
package main

func main() {
    go fun2()
    <-ch
    <-ch
}
func fun2() {
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
}

var ch = make(chan int)
```

Here `fun2()` sends two values and `main()` receives two values.

---

Your sample code has only one end point so the channel is not correctly constructed, so it is **deadlock**, but the `main` goroutines exits normally so you don't see the error. Here, there is no second end point, so this is deadlock:

```
package main

func main() {
    var ch = make(chan int)
    ch <- 1
}
```

Output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```